# looping in javascript

Tags: javascript

as before the below code is in a while loop . it out puts values id=pro0 then next loop through i get id=pro1 and if i have another record i get id=pro3

```
print "<td><input style=\"text-align:center\" type=\"text\" name=\"productitemsupdate_$num\" value=\"$row[productitems]\" size=\"5\" id=\"pro$num\"></td>";
```

the above code works with

```
var pro = document.getElementById('pro0');
```

what im after is a loop in java script which will take the last $num from the php from and use that for the amount of times to loop the javascript function.

something like this i think

```
var i=0;
while (i<=$num) {
    var pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro'[i]);
    if (pro[i].value == "") {
        inlineMsg('pro'[i],'This cannot Be blank'[i],10);
        return false;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

breaks when it is false when all fields are right it is true.
if i get this working it will save me guessing how many variable to check.

i have tried this but i cant this working either

```
var i=0;
var pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
for(var i = 0; i < <?php $num ?>; i++) {
    if(pro[i].value == "")
        alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
    return false;
}
```

this works but only for the first line. if the 2nd line is emtpy and the first line is not it does not produce the alert

```
var i=0;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var pro = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
if(pro.value == "")
alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)


return false;
}
```

i also changed the $num variable to a static number for my test record to see if it was my variable not being passed and it still did't work for the 2nd record any ideas

thanks

steve

working solution thanks for your help

```
var i=0;
var pro = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
if(pro[i].value == ""){
    alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
return false;}
```

}

Comment: @Belina: you're joking, right?

Comment: Are you really sure that your code does what you expect? I added formatting for your code (I only added whitespaces, not changed any other character) and I'm not sure about your `return false` at the end of first `for` loop run...

Comment: yes if the first result it gets to is blank i need it to exit . and then when it is filled in if the next row is empty then it exits there

Comment: See my edit. You're missing braces for the `if` block.

Comment: exactly, just worked that out before logging back in lol thanks matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, you concatenate strings using `+`. Therefore, you need to write

```
pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
```

For your loop, that'd look something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $num ?>; i++) {

    ...

}
```

Complete code:

```
var i=0;
var pro = [];
for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $num ?>; i++) {
    pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
    if(pro[i].value == "") {
        alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you don't need the actual array for anything, for later, you could simply do:

```
var i=0;
for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $num ?>; i++) {
    var pro = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
    if(pro.value == "") {
        alert("You entered: " + pro.value)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ive updated my post with your code but i just cant get it to work

Comment: I believe the `$num` should be echoed to print to the output. `<?php echo $num ?>`

Comment: sorry, I shouldn't have left the `var` keyword there, in the first line of code. `pro[i]` assumes an array already exists, it doesn't declare a new variable. Also, that line of code should be inside your loop. The way it is right now, it will only be executed once, and always with `i=0`.

Comment: @Steve: It's been ages since I wrote any PHP. Isn't `<?php $num ?>` shorthand for `<?php echo $num ?>` ?

Comment: thanks guys ill give this another ago. this is fast reponse time. ;)

Comment: @David: yeah, I'm really not a PHP guy at all. I just try to transfer knowledge from JSP to PHP for the basics.

Comment: all sorted now. i updated first post with working solution. thanks for all your help david

Comment: I think this will break if a missing field is encountered - it will be undefined and you cannot get .value from it.  See my answer for a fix to that.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server-side. JavaScript is client-side. If you want to insert a PHP variable into JavaScript, you have to treat your JS like HTML and use PHP to create the script. Something like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<script>
    var num = <?php echo $num ?>;
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

Then you can use this value of `num` elsewhere, even in external scripts (as long as `num` is declared beforehand).

---

#### Edit

Your `if` statement in the `for` loop is missing braces. Try this:

```
var i=0,
    pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);

for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $num ?>; i++) {
    if(pro[i].value == "")
    {
        alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make sure that this JS is actually being processed by PHP. The easiest way to do that is to put the code into an inline `<script>` tag.

Comment: Don't you have to `echo` the `$num` to print it to the HTML?

Comment: You're right, I was mixing up the shorthand for `echo`, ex. `<?=$num?>`

Answer (score 0):

What ever your PHP (not my expertise), here is an example looping through: http://jsfiddle.net/UpG57/

Comment: Your demo has a minor type. Would you mind putting the code into your answer as well? I'm not sure if there are any guarantees about how long fiddles will stick around if you don't save them to an account.